# Search function mixed with json and php (sql)

Tags: php, sql, json

I write a search system, this system has 4 pages/steps, on the first 3 pages are only checkboxes to find, my problem is, i create this checkboxes per json, and i can read only names. To convert this data for checkboxes i use:

```
<?php
$jsonData = json_decode($string5, true);
foreach ($jsonData  as $item) :
?>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" value="" /><?php echo $item['name'] ?></label><br />
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

My questions are:
How can i get values from checkboxes on the page/step 4 dynamicly? 
How can i from this json data create a sql query for search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
<?php
$jsonData = json_decode($string5, true);
foreach ($jsonData  as $item) :
?>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" /><?php echo $item['name'] ?></label><br />
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

In your PHP you can now get the value by something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$checkvalue = $_POST['checkbox'];
echo $checkvalue;
}
```

Now you can just add the $checkvalue into your DB, or do another query with it.

Comment: I know this part with $_POST, but my names are dynamic, the client can add more options in backoffice. Thats reason why i ask.

Comment: The name can always be the same, it's the value which is different right?

Comment: Right, this problem i have now solved :), firstly the is as array: mycheckbox[] and after this implode(',', $POST['mycheckbox'])